# Is it possible to force Gradle to downgrade version of some dependency with particular extension

Tags: gradle

I have dependencies on several plugins in project. These dependencies are put in *plugins* directory during project build. Here is the example:

```
plugin 'com.company:some-plugin:1.0@msi'
plugin 'com.company:some-plugin:1.0@pkg'
```

Now it is time to upgrade plugin version but for some reason I want to keep version of plugin for Mac (pkg) unchanged:

```
plugin 'com.company:some-plugin:2.0@msi'
plugin 'com.company:some-plugin:1.0@pkg'
```

How can I do it? Regular `force` does not help. What I see now is that Gradle upgrades version of all dependencies without considering of extension.

P.S. I use Gradle 5.2